# General::ivar: 1 is not a valid variable

Tags: fitting, warning-messages

```
fp = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}, {5, 6}, {6, 10}, {7, 14}, {8, 
    20}, {9, 20}, {10, 35}, {11, 46}, {12, 65}, {13, 83}, {14, 
    119}, {15, 137}, {16, 151}, {17, 185}, {18, 239}, {19, 273}, {20, 
    310}, {21, 370}, {22, 409}, {23, 477}, {24, 512}, {25, 582}, {26, 
    652}, {27, 702}, {28, 755}, {29, 806}, {30, 840}, {31, 884}, {32, 
    1013}};
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[fp, a (1 - Exp (-b (x - 1)))^c, {a, b, c}, x]
```

My code is like this. I want to figure out the parameters of this non linear model, but it kept showing this error. I don't know how to figure it out.

Comment: functions in Mathematica use `[ ]` not `( )`. So need to correct the call to `Exp` in your code and see if this fixes things.

Comment: Thank you. Here is another error occured.
"NonlinearModelFit::nrlnum: The function value {-1.+1.[1. -1. exp[Times[<<2>>]]]^1.,-2.+1.[1. -1. exp[Times[<<2>>]]]^1.,<<28>>,-884.+1.[1. -1. exp[Times[<<2>>]]]^1.,-1013.+1.[1. -1. exp[Times[<<2>>]]]^1.} is not a list of real numbers with dimensions {32} at {a,b,c} = {1.,1.,1.}."

Comment: Try to change your model. When I tried this I get no error `nlm = NonlinearModelFit[fp, a (Exp[-b (x - 1)])^c, {a, b, c}, x]`  $$\frac{37.1132}{\left(e^{-0.274286 (x-1)}\right)^{0.397136}}$$  But I do not know why it gives `NonlinearModelFit::nrjnum` otherwise. I am not a fitting expert. May be someone else would know. But please edit your post and correct your code.

Comment: OK. As this model is offered by my professor, it didn't come to me that I can change it. This actually works. Thank you!

Comment: @HanqiYu Be sure to use `Exp` not `exp` as in your comment.